# Amazon CLI, route 53, TXT error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I'm trying to create a TXT record in Route53 via the Amazon CLI for DNS-01 validation.  Seems like I'm very close but possibly running into a CLI issue (or a formatting issue I don't see).  As you can see, it's complaining about a value that should be in quotes, but is indeed in quotes already...

Command Line:

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ID_HERE --change-batch file://c:\dev\test1.json
```

JSON File:

```
{
"Changes": [
    {
        "Action": "UPSERT",
        "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "DOMAIN_NAME_HERE",
            "Type": "TXT",
            "TTL": 60,
            "ResourceRecords": [
                {
                    "Value": "test"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

Error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidChangeBatch) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: Invalid Resource Record: FATAL problem: InvalidCharacterString (Value should be enclosed in quotation marks) encountered with 'test'
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Those quotes are the JSON quotes, and those are not the quotes they're looking for.

The JSON string `"test"` encodes the literal value `test`.

The JSON string `"\"test\""` encodes the literal value `"test"`.

(This is because in [JSON](http://json.org), a literal `"` in a string is escaped with a leading `\`).

It sounds like they want actual, literal quotes included *inside* the value, so if you're building this JSON manually you probably want the latter: `"Value": "\"test\""`.

A JSON library should do this for you if you passed it the value with the leading and trailing `"` included.

Comment: Spot on.  Thanks!  Interesting that they don't want all string parameters provided with escaped quotes like this.

Comment: That's because this is a `TXT` record, which [is a quoted string, by definition](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1464)... so Route 53 expects to see actual quotes inside the record.

Comment: *"A TXT record contains a space-separated list of double-quoted strings."* -- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#TXTFormat

Comment: Makes sense now.  Thanks again.

Comment: these are not the quotes you're lookin for... :).  Thanks @Michael-sqlbot! Would've expected AWS to detect and automatically fix this

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot And Amazon is, apparently, above making it easier for everyone else by simply detecting a predictable issue like this in their CLI tool and applying the required formatting.  Hooray!

Comment: Confirming that this works with the shorthand syntax as well: `--change-batch 'Changes=[{Action=UPSERT,ResourceRecordSet={Name=some.domain,Type=TXT,TTL=300,ResourceRecords=[{Value="\"here goes the value\""}]}}]'`

Comment: Helped!

        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "\"123.cloudfront.net\""
          }
        ]