# Unable to create a simple TXT record set in Amazon Route 53 using the AWS CLI

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I am getting below error while creating TXT record in Route53 using AWS CLI. Please let me know where I am doing mistake.

Error:

> [Invalid Resource Record: 'FATAL problem: InvalidCharacterString (Value should be enclosed in quotation marks) encountered with '376ae6f4-8cf5-4d91-9246-fd3d6069ebf8'']

Code:

```
{
        "Comment": "Create a recored",
        "Changes": [{
        "Action": "CREATE",
                "ResourceRecordSet":{
                        "Name": "profpoint-verification",
                        "Type": "TXT",
                        "TTL": 300,
                        "ResourceRecords": [{"Value":"3766f4-8cf5-4d91-9246-fd3d699ebf8"}]
                }
        }]
}
```

I referred to [Create a simple resource record set in Amazon Route 53 using the AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/simple-resource-record-route53-cli/) to create the above code.

Comment: for txt records, you need quotes around the value

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by adding escape quotation marks:

```
{
    "Comment": "proofpoint-verification",
    "Changes": [{
        "Action": "CREATE",
        "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "proofpoint-verification.mydomain",
            "Type": "TXT",
            "TTL": 300,
            "ResourceRecords": [{
                "Value": "\"3766f4-8cf5-4d91-9246-fd3d699ebf8\""
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731295/amazon-cli-route-53-txt-error) is a detailed explanation

Comment: I want to add same record with multiple zone. can you suggest any  script?

Comment: Glad that it worked!  It would be better to create a separate question about cycling through the bash script commands, because that would be definitely outside of scope of your original question.  Could you please upvote this response and close it as a resolution to this question and create a new question (with the reference to this one if you want to mention the json file).